# Simple phantom power for condenser mic

Tags: power, pc, phantom

I am on a tight budget, and would like to some voice recording (e.g. podcasts). I have a decent condenser mic, but I do not have a phantom power supply. The phantom power supply/interface only needs one channel, and all it needs to do is provide phantom power. I have an XLR-XLR cable to connect my mic to the power supply/interface and an XLR-USB cable (no phantom power) to connect from the interface to my computer.

This is one I have been looking at: [http://www.amazon.com/InnoGear%C2%AE-Condenser-Microphone-Recording-Equipment/dp/B00KAPGLQC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KAPGLQC)

Will this do what I want? If not, what is an affordable phantom power supply for my 48V condenser mic? And is connecting the power supply/interface with an XLR-USB cable non-ideal?

Comment: Here is a good website (french but you can use google translate) to do your own phantom power [link](http://www.sonelec-musique.com/electronique_bases_alim_phantom.html), I also found this [post](http://homerecording.com/bbs/equipment-forums/microphones/phantom-power-105128/#post961540)

Comment: That piece will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The product you linked is the one for the job. And since you give to your condenser mic the power it needs to operate, you can connect it anywhere you could connect any dynamic mic, such as a simple XLR-USB audio interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need an inline UBS interface like this [Blue Icicle](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/571273-REG/Blue_ICICLE_Icicle_USB_Microphone.html)  - others are cheaper but at $49, this is a decent, simple option.